# python groupwise winsorization and linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am new to the python world. I have to deal with financial datasets. Say I have a data frame looks like this:

```
TradingDate StockCode       Size     ILLIQ
0    20050131    000001  13.980320   77.7522
1    20050131    000002  14.071253   19.1471
2    20050131    000004  10.805564  696.2428
3    20050131    000005  11.910485  621.3723
4    20050131    000006  11.631550  339.0952
*** ***
```

What I want to do is to do a groupwise OLS regression, where the grouping varibales is TradingDate, the dependent variable is 'Size', the independent variable is 'ILLIQ'. I would like to append the residual item of the regressions back to the original Dataframe, say a new column named 'Residual'. How can I hanlde this?

It seems the following code is not working?

```
def regress(data,yvar,xvars):
    Y = data[yvar]
    X = data[xvars]
    X['intercept']=1.
    result = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
    return result.resid()

by_Date = df.groupby('TradingDate')
by_Date.apply(regress,'ILLIQ',['Size'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `.resid` to access the residuals -  `.resid` just an attribute, not a method ([see docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html)). Simplified illustration:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
df = df.set_index('TradingDate', inplace=True)
df['residuals'] = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(sm.ols(formula="Size ~ ILLIQ", data=x).fit().resid)).values

             StockCode       Size     ILLIQ  residuals
TradingDate                                           
20050131             1  13.980320   77.7522   0.299278
20050131             2  14.071253   19.1471   0.132318
20050131             4  10.805564  696.2428  -0.153800
20050131             5  11.910485  621.3723   0.621652
20050131             6  11.631550  339.0952  -0.899448
```

Comment: I tried your code, it gives out the following error:
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: I think I moved `TradingDate` to the index first, let me update the answer.

Comment: Actually I have set the index to the TradingDate column when importing the data from SQL DB:
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con,index_col=['TradingDate'])

Comment: It seems that I have some NaN values in the ILLIQ columns, which makes the length of resid columns shorter than that of the number of rows in original dataframe.

Comment: That would explain things. `.dropna()` would solve this.

Comment: The problem is that I might need to keep those NaN values in my dataframe while still conducting this groupwise regression...

Comment: You could take out the `np.nan` values before running the regression using `df[pd.isnull(df.ILLIQ)]`, `.dropna()` on the rest and use `pd.concat()` to combine again after running the `OLS`.

Answer (score 0):

## Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """TradingDate StockCode       Size     ILLIQ
0    20050131    000001  13.980320   77.7522
1    20050131    000002  14.071253   19.1471
2    20050131    000004  10.805564  696.2428
3    20050131    000005  11.910485  621.3723
4    20050131    000006  11.631550  339.0952"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=1,
                 converters=dict(TradingDate=pd.to_datetime))
```

## Solution

```
def regress(data,yvar,xvars):
    # I changed this a bit to ensure proper dimensional alignment
    Y = data[[yvar]].copy()
    X = data[xvars].copy()
    X['intercept'] = 1
    result = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
    # resid is an attribute not a method
    return result.resid

def append_resids(df, yvar, xvars):
    """New helper to return DataFrame object within groupby apply
    df = df.copy()
    df['residuals'] = regress(df, yvar, xvars)
    return df

df.groupby('TradingDate').apply(lambda x: append_resids(x, 'ILLIQ', ['Size']))
```